# Nested queries against the Google Knowledge Graph API?

Tags: google-api, semantic-web, google-knowledge-graph

I was playing around with the Knowledge Graph API recently, but can't really get it to return anything useful.

My scenario is this: I query the API for `maxim gorki theater`, and it rightly returns the entry for the theater in Berlin. Now, on the web, I can click `Kommende Veranstaltungen` [Upcoming events] and it gives me the next plays for that theater. This is still part of the knowledge graph, the displayed search term is `maxim gorki theater kommende veranstaltungen`. Yet if I try to pass that query to the API to get a JSON of the next plays I am simply returned an empty result.

My query is this: `https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=QUERY&key=API_KEY&limit=1&indent=True`

Am I doing this wrong or is this a general limitation of the API? If so, what is the point of this API?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the code from https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/, It works well

`service_url = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search'
params = {
    'query': query,
    'limit': 10,
    'indent': True,
    'key': api_key,
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
response = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())`

Comment: That is indeed a standard query that works perfectly well. My question was about subqueries, i.e. queries for items that are connect to a given other item in the graph.